# sqlite DB doesn't get wrapp in my exe

Tags: java, sqlite

I have created a Java Swing program which uses a SQLite database to store the hardware details of the pc. When I run that program as a java application, hardware details get stored in the DB. I have to generate an exe of that java program. I created an exe using ant build, launch4j and Innosetup. I added the DB(sys_data.db) in launch4j in classpath. But when I run that exe, the hardware details doesn't stored in the DB.

Any suggestion please?

Comment: Have you put your SQLite jar in the classpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A database is not a jar file - therefore this is totally unrelated to the classpath. If you load the db by a relative path the program will search in the current directory.

My suggestion would be to use a fully qualified path when loading the SQLite database. You can retrieve for example the path where your main jar is located - see [How to get the path of a running JAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file) for details.